# Verify only needed parameters exists when creating stack in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, parameters, stack, verification

I'm using the AWS SDK in java to create a stack using the cloud formation.
My problem is that AWS forbidden sending parameters that do not exists in the JSON template of the stack and of course will throw an exception in case one of the parameters was not filled.

Is there a way to validate my request to create the stack without really creating the stack?

I've already looked at verify-template but it's only verifying locally the JSON template for errors and is not related to the parameters (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-validate-template.html)

Answer (score 0):

I eventually used getTemplateSummary method from AmazonCloudFormationClient and iterated over the parameters and than verified that the user sent the exact parameters in order to create the Stack